# Unable to get the background color of WPF's TextBox control

Tags: c++, wpf, winapi, textbox

I try to use this interface `IUIAutomationTextRange` to get the foreground Color and background color of the `TextBox`.

```cpp
GetAttributeValue(UIA_ForegroundColorAttributeId, &ForeRGB);
```

This function can get the foreground RGB of the control.

```cpp
GetAttributeValue(UIA_BackgroundColorAttributeId, &BackRGB);
```

The `BackRGB` value of this function is always 0.

I'm sure I set the background color of TextBox to blue.

Comment: Those attributes relate to the `TextRange`, not the control.

Comment: How to get TextBox background color?What does  BackRGB value mean?

Comment: You can't get background color from TextRange pattern, it's related to TextElement.BackgroundProperty (see WPF source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/TextRangeAdaptor.cs,66) which is not settable on TextBox AFAIK. If you own the control, the only way would be to use some UI Automation property you don't use and can set (for example: AutomationProperties.HelpText). In general you can check what you can read or not using the Inspect tool from the SDK on the target app, you'll see everything before any coding

Comment: I'm not aware of a supported way to query the background color brush setting of a WPF `TextBox` control. `BackRGB` is the background color applied to the `TextRange`. This is commonly used by controls that support text formatting. `TextBox` does not.